# How to type and "arrow" with a stop on both ends in PlainTeX?

Tags: math-mode, plain-tex

I'm trying to insert a line segment symbol but I'm unable to find the correct "arrow" to use with

`\buildrel \SEGMENT_ARROW \over AB`.

I'm trying to achieve something like this

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a minimum working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution for your similar question works with small changes:

```
\input stmary

\catcode`@=11
\def\segment#1{%
  \mathord{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{##\cr
      $\m@th\scriptscriptstyle{\mapstochar\relbar}
       \leaderbar
       {\relbar\mkern-1mu\mapsfromchar}$\cr
      $\m@th#1$\cr
    }%
  }}%
}

\def\leaderbar{%
  \mkern-7mu
  \cleaders\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-2mu{\relbar}\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
  \mkern-7mu
}
\catcode`@=12

$\segment{AB}$

\bye
```

[image]